# Elm 0.17 Simple Mouse.clicks example

Tags: elm

To get familiar with `subscriptions` in 0.17 I'm trying to get a simple app going that subscribes to Mouse.clicks and would increment the `Model` by one.

At the moment the app has the following complaint.

**Function `program` is expecting the argument to be:**

```
{ ...  
  , subscriptions : Float -> Sub Msg  
  , update : Msg -> Float -> ( Float, Cmd Msg )  
  , view : Float -> Html Msg   
}
```

**But it is:**

```
{ ...  
  , subscriptions : (Msg -> Position -> a) -> Sub a  
  , update : Msg -> number -> ( number, Cmd b )  
  , view : c -> Html d  
}
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

```
import Html exposing (Html, text, div)
import Html.App as Html
import Mouse exposing (..)

main =
  Html.program
    { init = init
    , view = view
    , update = update
    , subscriptions = subscriptions
    }

-- MODEL

type alias Model = Int

init : (Model, Cmd Msg)
init =
  (0, Cmd.none)

-- UPDATE

type Msg
  = Click

update msg model =
  case msg of
    Click ->
      (model + 1 , Cmd.none)

-- SUBSCRIPTIONS

subscriptions model =
  Mouse.clicks (model Click)

-- VIEW

view model =
  Html.text (toString model)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `subscriptions` function. You'll need to set it up like this:

```elm
subscriptions model =
  Mouse.clicks (\_ -> Click)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Spot on!